# How to prevent Alfresco transforation server application to stop:

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-enterprise, alfresco-maven

The transformation server goes down after 5-6 months. The temp files in tomcat\temp is not released event after the server stop. So we have only one option is to reboot the server.

```
  15-Nov-2018 14:33:48.919 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [transformation-server] appears to have started a thread named [Directory Watcher (12345678Somefilename.version.pdf.11_(CE)56804616958243633347789395989933437100.pdf)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
     sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.poll(AbstractWatchService.java:108)
     com.some.com.alfresco.transformation.transformer.external.esmonitor.DirectoryWatcher.watch(DirectoryWatcher.java:86)
     com.some.com.alfresco.transformation.transformer.external.esmonitor.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:48)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.028 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [transformation-server] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-2021] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus0(Native Method)
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(WindowsNativeDispatcher.java:1007)
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.run(WindowsWatchService.java:571)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.028 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [transformation-server] appears to have started a thread named [Directory Watcher (12345678Somefilename.version.pdf.13_(CE)72889340369927099637716823898807491840.pdf)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
     sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.poll(AbstractWatchService.java:108)
     com.some.com.alfresco.transformation.transformer.external.esmonitor.DirectoryWatcher.watch(DirectoryWatcher.java:86)
     com.some.com.alfresco.transformation.transformer.external.esmonitor.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:48)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.028 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [transformation-server] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-2028] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus0(Native Method)
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(WindowsNativeDispatcher.java:1007)
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.run(WindowsWatchService.java:571)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.028 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [transformation-server] appears to have started a thread named [Directory Watcher (12345678Somefilename.version.pdf.15_(CE)63650266326795937045488961376688239135.pdf)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
     sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.poll(AbstractWatchService.java:108)
     com.some.com.alfresco.transformation.transformer.external.esmonitor.DirectoryWatcher.watch(DirectoryWatcher.java:86)
     com.some.com.alfresco.transformation.transformer.external.esmonitor.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:48)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.028 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [transformation-server] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-2029] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus0(Native Method)
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(WindowsNativeDispatcher.java:1007)
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.run(WindowsWatchService.java:571)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.028 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [transformation-server] appears to have started a thread named [Directory Watcher (12345678Somefilename.version.pdf.13_(CE)72889340369927099637716823898807491840.pdf)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
     sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.poll(AbstractWatchService.java:108)
     com.some.com.alfresco.transformation.transformer.external.esmonitor.DirectoryWatcher.watch(DirectoryWatcher.java:86)
     com.some.com.alfresco.transformation.transformer.external.esmonitor.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:48)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.028 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [transformation-server] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-2033] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus0(Native Method)
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(WindowsNativeDispatcher.java:1007)
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.run(WindowsWatchService.java:571)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.028 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [transformation-server] appears to have started a thread named [Directory Watcher (12345678Somefilename.version.pdf.13_(CE)72889340369927099637716823898807491840.pdf)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:522)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:684)
     sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.poll(AbstractWatchService.java:108)
     com.some.com.alfresco.transformation.transformer.external.esmonitor.DirectoryWatcher.watch(DirectoryWatcher.java:86)
     com.some.com.alfresco.transformation.transformer.external.esmonitor.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:48)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.028 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [transformation-server] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-2034] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus0(Native Method)
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(WindowsNativeDispatcher.java:1007)
     sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.run(WindowsWatchService.java:571)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.075 INFO [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.153 INFO [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
    15-Nov-2018 14:33:49.262 INFO [WrapperListener_stop_runner] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Destroying 2 processes
    Destroying process..
    Destroying process..
    Destroyed 2 processes
    Launching a JVM...
    JVM exited while loading the application.
    Launching a JVM...
    JVM exited while loading the application.
    Launching a JVM...
    JVM exited while loading the application.
    Launching a JVM...
    JVM exited while loading the application.
    Launching a JVM...
    JVM exited while loading the application.
    There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
      There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
    <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

The transformation server goes down after 5-6 months. The temp files in tomcat\temp is not released event after the server stop. So we have only one option is to reboot the server. Any insight or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Alfresco Transformation Server is only available to paying Alfresco Enterprise customers. So, since you've paid for it, why not ring up Alfresco support and ask them for help? After all, that's much of what you're paying for!

Comment: You only have theses logs ?

Comment: @Akah i have all acces to server and its configuration files but i can not do changes in java source files. Is there anything should i need to check on configuration side.Transformation server is installed in window machine and have .net version of 3.5.1